# Fetch data using meteor client via chrome dev tools

Tags: meteor

Some data sent from server to client are intentionally filtered. Lets say that we have some raw plain-text "Foo, bar" , in client collection we have "Foo, *hidden*". Is there any way to read raw data before they are filtered?

Comment: Can you elaborate on exactly what it is that you want to get? Where is the desired data and what means does the client have to get this data? Was this data ever published to the client? What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 0):

The client doesn't see anything until it's done being processed by the server. [Understanding Meteor Publications and Subscriptions](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/) talks some about this (with pictures). The data published to the client is the product of the function that is run on the server - it has no notion of the actual server side database.

If you want some users to be able to see this data but not others, consider logic in the publication to provide some users with the unfiltered data.

If you want to see it for debug purposes, you can have the server print (`console.log('filtering out',rawText)`) as it processes the content (depending on how the filter is being applied) such that you (who has access to the meteor server terminal) can see the content.

Comment: I'm arguing with friend who wrote simple app that outputs some basic system (linux) information, but some of them are hidden (like kernel version). I think that collection with `uname -a` command output is sent as raw data and filtered in client.

Comment: At this level you're talking inspecting the Meteor data on the wire. Found this package [meteor-ddp-inspector](https://github.com/rclai/meteor-ddp-inspector) ([atmosphere link](https://atmospherejs.com/lai/ddp-inspector)), have not used it. May reveal what's going on.